# Monit versus Nagios

Tags: monitoring, nagios, monit

Does nagios offer any additional functionality when compared to monit?

This [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/177683/46333) states that monit is a clumsy tool for situational awareness, which is the reason I'm asking the question.

Comment: Nagios is like the Swiss Army knife of monitoring tools, it is hugely configurable and flexible. Have a look at Centreon (http://www.centreon.com/) which is a real nice front end to nagios (or their own fork of nagios core).

Comment: @Kev your comment doesn't really help for my question, if I hadn't terribly misunderstood you

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes. [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) has support for custom scripts and checks, better integration and more granular notification options. [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) is good for basic system checks and daemons monitoring. Nagios is more flexible, but is also more involved to install.

I find that Monit is good for single-host installations, but [multi-Monit (M/Monit)](http://mmonit.com/) really isn't that good of a central console solution. It's good for [up/down views at a glance,](http://mmonit.com/screenshots/images/screenshots/3.png) but falls over with a larger number of hosts or when you need to monitor systems over the WAN. The interface is also too simple.

I find that multiple tools are often needed to provide a good view of an environment. Monit is great for making sure things are running. It's simple enough to get running and can alert if a process that should be present isn't. Think of ntp, sshd, crond, etc. Use Monit to take corrective actions based on that.

---

My approach over the past few years has required Monit for daemon and custom application monitoring via PID file. [Observium](http://www.observium.org/wiki/Main_Page) or [ORCA](http://www.orcaware.com/orca/) for graphing and trends analysis. [OpenNMS](http://www.opennms.org/) for up/down and notifications. I've yet to find a suite that does it all cleanly. Observium doen't do alerts. Orca is graphing-only, OpenNMS has great notifications and thresholding, but *ugly* graphs.

I don't use Nagios because of the setup involved and my familiarity with other tools.  I've inherited a few Nagios installations that went awry because of poor implementation. I find that OpenNMS + Monit + an RRDTool-based graphing solution work better for me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer & the edits :), is there anything specific that you can do with nagios and cannot do with monit. You seem to be versed in both, I have literally zero knowledge of nagios, I would really appreciate some points in that regard.

Comment: Nagios can do everything Monit can, but worth more effort up-front. I don't use Nagios because of this.

Comment: @ewwhite How suited is Monit for using Nagios plugins?

Comment: Monit also supports custom checks: - https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#PROGRAM-STATUS-TEST